# Div won't fill size of parent container

Tags: css, html

I have a problem in which I am making a website which will have a main content section and a "Updates" bar on the right side. Here is the link. http://bebiafricanhairbraiding.com/

You should be able to get the code from the website itself but if you need the code I can post it here. 
Thanks.

Comment: Oh God, it burns.

What is your problem exactly? Which div are you having a problem with?

Comment: My problem is that the updates div is supposed to be the same size as the content div. They are both contained in the "Bottom Wrap". They should take the size of the Bottom Wrap by setting the height to 100%. But it doesn't.

Comment: @Mike I'm a bit confused as well.  Please post some code, possibly include some pictures as well please.

Comment: @DadeLamkins I cannot post pictures because of my repuation level and I am having trouble "properly formatting" the code when entering it. I also cannot post more than one link and there are more links in the code. So if you could please go to the link, you should be able to get the code form there.

Comment: You're after ["equal height columns"](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+equal+height+columns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it really important that the div's are the same height, or that the background is the same length? I guess the latter. Instead of trying to get the div's to be the same height (which won't work), create two positioned div's and set the background on their parent. The rounded corners at the bottom should be done in a separate footer element.

So like this:

```
+-----+-----+
| a   | b   |
|     +-----+
|     |
+-----------+
| c         |
+-----------+
```

a is your content column, b is your sidebar. Both are (together) contained in a parent div, which has a background. c is the footer with rounded corners.

See also http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/.

I would also really recommend to use a css framework like http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/. This makes it a lot easier to make grids, nice typography, etc.

Answer (score -2):

#content has height:100% and
  #update has height:250px

Set the updates height

```
#updates {height:100%}
```

Comment: Did you even try this? It would only work if the parent element (#bottomwrap) had an explicit height set. It currently has a height of 0px.